# vscode file association regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, glob

I am trying to get my vscode workspace to expect all files without an extension to be js files.

I wrote this regex to select files without a `.`, but I can't get it to work. You can use regex here, right? I couldn't find this in the docs, so I am guessing.

```json
{
    "files.associations": {
        "^([^.]+)$": "javascript"
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not look like you can use regex here, it looks like the [app expects a glob](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_adding-a-file-extension-to-a-language) here.

Comment: The duplicate question has a good answer for you.